# XML attribute to element using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have following XML,  elements are dynamically generated and can change from time to time, therefore I can't hard code field name,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
   <datacollection id="amazon_order.1">
   <table name="order_detail">
       <row name="default_options">
           <field name="zipCode">800227028</field>
           <field name="customerLastName">COMER</field>
           <field name="state">CO</field>
           <field name="city">COMMERCE CITY</field>
           <field name="serialNumber">818243CX601252Y</field>           
       </row>
     </table>
     </datacollection>
```

And want to transform it into following format using XSLT,

```
<datacollection id="amazon_order.1">
<table name="order_detail">
   <row name="default_options">
       <zipCode>800227028</zipCode>
       <customerLastName>COMER</customerLastName>
       <state>CO</state>
       <city>COMMERCE CITY</city>
       <serialNumber>818243CX601252Y</serialNumber>                      
   </row>
</table>
</datacollection>
```

Comment: So you want to convert each `<field>` element to an element named by the original element's `name` attribute, leaving everything else unchanged?

Comment: yes, everything should stay as is.

Answer (score 2):

You want to transform `<field>` elements to output elements having variable names derived from the original elements' attributes.  That calls for a template matching the original elements and creating corresponding new ones via an XSL `element` element.  You want to keep everything else the same, so that calls for an identity transform to handle everything else, both outside and inside the erstwhile `<field>` elements.

Assuming that your `<field>` elements will never have attributes other than `name` that need to carry over to the result document, that would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!-- identity transform for otherwise-unmatched nodes and attributes -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- transform for field elements at any depth -->
  <xsl:template match="field">
    <xsl:element name="{@name}">
      <!-- transform this node's non-attribute children -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```